# Site Guest User not allowed to make callout

Tags: force.com-sites, rest, apexrest

I have exposed a Rest service method to public

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/webhook')
global class Services {
    Private static String ACTION_PARAM =  'action';
    Private static String FETCH_UPDATES =  'fetchUpdates';

    @HttpPost
    global static void  handleRequest() {
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        try{

            response.addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            String action = req.params.get(ACTION_PARAM);
            Object result;
            if(FETCH_UPDATES.equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                result = ServicesHandler.fetchUpdates(req.requestBody.toString());
            }
            response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(String.valueOf(result));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Here fetchUpdate method do some callout to an external system Like below request

[image]

When I do this request from Postman, it gives expected result but from apex it gives below response

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]
```

So My questions are :

1. Does site guest user is not allowed to make any external service callout?
2. My classes are running without with sharing, so they should run in god mode, so why they are not getting result.
3. AM I doing something wrong?

Please let me know if anyone need more information to add some more context.

Please help me

Comment: Do you have a [Remote Site Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm) configured in this org allowing callouts to this URL?

Comment: @MarkPond That would have created a CalloutException.

Comment: Does changing HttpPost to HttpGet on handleRequest() fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Method Not Allowed" is a specific HTTP error that means you've used the *wrong method*. It has nothing to do with authentication, an invalid endpoint, etc. It simply means you're trying to do something you haven't allowed (e.g. you're trying to perform a GET instead of a POST).

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. I've made callouts back to Salesforce itself (which requires remote site settings to be made) under the site guest user so I doubt that is the problem.
2. The "god mode" idea relates to access rights to Salesforce data not external web services so is not relevant.
3. So the first place I would look is the implementation of `ServicesHandler.fetchUpdates`, confirming that the endpoint is identical to the one that works in your manual test, that the right method is being used, and that the [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is correctly constructed and set in the right header.

Just tried this callout code from a site and it worked fine so item 1 isn't the problem:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/proxy')
global class Proxy {
    @HttpGet
    global static String get() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        return new Http().send(req).getBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: 405 means the wrong "http verb" has been used for the service, for example, using `POST / HTTP/1.1` when the path doesn't support POST.

Comment: @sfdcfox Because I was doing a `GET` request and was also setting Body for the request like `request.setBody(data);` . When I commented this, it works.

Comment: Below paste snippet is my Java Rest implementation

http://pastebin.com/embed_js/9BhduvSQ

Comment: @SFDCGOD A little known tidbit: GET doesn't support a body. If you set the body, this overrides the method from GET to POST.

Comment: @sfdcfox as per your comment, if I set body in a get request, it will convert 'GET' request into 'POST' .

But when I see the debugs , request shows as it executed as 'GET' request.

Comment: @SFDCGOD It doesn't matter how it debugs, it matters how the server actually sends it. The HttpRequest object is only the requested configuration. The code that actually opens the connection will adjust your request accordingly. I can probably write up a demo to show it in action.